# Change H1 Title for Blog Index Without Killing URL

Tags: html, css, shopify

Shopify is listing the word 'Blog' as my H1 title for the entire indexed blog page and any sub-articles.

How can I change this word to be more specific for my SEO. I

 https://samplified.us/blogs/tutorials-and-free-downloads

I can edit it via. google, for H1 and it would make sense as is. I also want to make sure I don't break the URL but instead just change the HTML on the index page.

[Changing the H1 Title on my Blog Index Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6aei.png)

Comment: It's doing the same on this page as well, listing the top title "Sample Pack" as an H2 Title Instead of H1. https://samplified.us/collections/sample-packs

Answer (score 0):

Well to change Blog title you need to a bit modify your code. For that you can go to your admin ->Theme ->Edit code ->Templates ->So you need edit blog.liquid and article.liquid to change H1 Title for Blog Index Without Killing URL.  If you have any question let me know. Thank you